# scala mongodb driver: NoSuchMethod

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Removing an entity from Database throws an exception. It used to work with the later version of casbah (before 3.x.x).

The exception is thrown from the class extending SalatDAO

```
   remove(MongoDBObject("_id" -> id))
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.WriteResult.getCachedLastError()
com.novus.salat.dao.SalatDAO.remove(SalatDAO.scala:376)
com.novus.salat.dao.BaseDAOMethods$class.remove(DAO.scala:195)
```

Comment: You might check this out: https://github.com/salat/salat/pull/157

Comment: wow, thank you :) I still would need to have that being fixed in the online version, however at least I know there is some problem with the library

Comment: @mfirry is there any other way how to remove an entity so that it would not throw an exception?